# How to ensure message delivery to SOAP endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm consuming a notoriously unreliable SOAP web service in a c# MVC project.  I have no control over that service.  It will occasionally just stop responding for extended periods.  Is there a simple way, from the client side,  to continue to retry sending the message, at a set interval, until I receive a response back from the service?

I've looked at MSMQ and ws-reliability but, it appears to me, both options require some control over the web service.  Is there anything out there to help me to do this from the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably already figured out, your problem is a huge problem for many. Look up "idempotent" and "webservice". Idempotency means a lot more than just being able to ensure a request/response, but a search will give you plenty of good stuff to read.

If "stop responding for extended periods" means seconds while seldomly called upon, DarkWanderer showed a pretty brute force solution to such a problem.

But if you have many calls, sleeping may eat up your working threads, so then you simply have to rely on some kind of queue.

If your calls are non-transactional and non-critical, you could surely code your own queing mechanism. While this may seem easy, it may still require threading, complex callbacks, logging, active error handling and what not. Many poor souls have reported that what started as a simple solution was turned into a maintainance nightmare.

And now I see that one of your requirements is that it must survive an app-pool recycling. Then we are in the last category of critical (and maybe transactional) queing.

Why I would recommend MSMQ from the very start. It handles all your problems and the api is in .net and really good nowadays. Yes, it will add complexity to your overall solution, but that stems from your problem domain.

Comment: I have no aversion to MSMQ but everything I *ahem* skimmed referred to queue to queue communication in MSMQ.  Can you point me to a tutorial or something pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: There are so many sources to pick from. And as I don't know the specifics of how and why you are calling that webservice there are so many options. But basically your incomming request should drop a message on the queue. Then you can the calling part that peek that message and if successful removes it from the queue. And then a startup check that consumes the queue and make sure all service calls are made. That is a very basic architecture.

Comment: I would still need an external service that monitors the queue, right?  My understanding is that MSMQ can't activate external code.

Comment: MSMQ is not re-active. But as I described above you could handle all this within an application. With the risk of negating my entire answer you could actually mimic this with one table in a database, and use transactions to treat that table as a queue. You could also be so blunt to only store failed call in this table/msmq. I still know too little about your application context to give a better answer

Comment: Thanks.  I was just hoping there was something out there that could activate my code on a schedule until success or hard failure.  I'll end up writing a daemon that monitors a queue, I don't know if I'll use MSMQ or a DB or something else yet, but you helped me get rid of that feeling that I was re-inventing the wheel.  It really sounds like there isn't something out there that does what I'm looking for, and it also seems like a really common, fairly simple requirement.  Anyway, sorry about the wall of text, you helped me out.

Comment: Well. If you plan for idempotency it affect and effect everything. 'Thank you for your order' becomes 'Your order is pending, you will be notified when something happens to it'. But it seems you just want an unstable service to work. Log errors and retry is the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true) {
    try {
        var response = webServiceClient.CallMethod();
        if (response.Successful())
            break;
        Sleep(retryInterval);
    } catch {}
}
```

---

And that means, you just need to keep calling the web-service, no message queue or something is required. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Okay, I didn't add I'm calling from a web application.  The app pool may recycle before this succeeds.  Updated my question with that important piece of info.

Comment: Then you need a simple intermediate service which serves as a message queue then. An own-written one would be faster to implement than MSMQ and would not require the server to be changed.